# How to find the key of XOR encryption in Java?

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, xor, decryption

I am trying to find the key of an XOR-encrypted string in Java. It is very probable that the key is eight characters long. I have the encrypted string.

I do not understand how to go backwards and find the encrypted string. I did some research and found out about [Vigenère cipher](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Vigenere-cipher), and some other things, which were partly too advanced for me, as I am new to this.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If your encrypted string is a text (not a random set of characters), then:

- If the text is short, use brute force. For very short texts there might by more than one solution.
- If the text is long, select a short range and use brute force. Then apply found key for the whole text. If the decrypted text contains too many words that are not in the dictionary, continue brute force with a small range till the next good key.

Both approaches require little resources and are very quick.

Answer (score 0):

The key to encrypt and decrypt are the same for XOR.

I’m not sure what you exactly need, because you mention that you have the encrypted string ad that you are trying to find the encrypted string.